# Encryption with password PHP

Tags: php, password-encryption

I'm making a website in which a user logs in with a password, that password is used as key to encrypt a string with a two-way encryption.

The password is also saved, unencrypted, into `$_SESSION` variable.

Is there a way to hash the password, save it into `$_SESSION` and finally use the hashed password to encrypt the string?

Comment: The answer is Yes. But you cannot unhash the hashed password. You would have to encrypt the other data with the hashed password

Comment: Right. And what I have to do to decrypt the string if the hash of a password is always changing?

Comment: @FedericoBelotti - you can't, if the password changes, then it can't be used to decrypt data that was encrypted using a previous password.... you'd have to decrypt and re-encrypt on change of password

Comment: Its normal to save a encryption key as of course it quite important to know what was used to encrypt something so you can decrypt it. I think we are all going to just be **guessing** unless you give more details about what you are actually trying to do

Comment: I'm trying to encrypt a text with a two-way encryption, using a key which is the password, possibly encrypted or hashed, that the user input at login time. My problem are: 1) I don't want to save it in a $_SESSION variable without hashing or encrypting it. 2) I can't hash it because I won't be able to decrypt the string later. So I'm guessing if there is a way to both have the password encrypted and saved in $_SESSION variable and use it to encrypt the string.

Comment: @RyanVincent right, but if I encrypt data with an hashed password, when I'm going to decrypt it I can't, because the data was encrypted with the old hashed password.

Comment: @RyanVincent so I have to declare it as a constant inside my code, am I right?

Comment: @RyanVincent you got me and I'm very thankful to you for your support :) now, suppose that I'm super paranoid, what other options I have left?

Comment: imo, Your over thinking it. write an encrypt function for a string that takes a string and and a password and returns an encrypted string. Write a decrypt function for a string that takes an encrypted string and a password. Ok?  You have them? see: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption. This is more than secure enough.

Comment: @RyanVincent so doing I'm not using anymore the user's password to encrypt the string but an encrypted password the i know. The user's password is only used to verify if that user can decrypt the data, am I right?

Comment: [php-encryption/example.php](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/example.php). Secure enough for most of us. :)

Comment: @RyanVincent do you suggest to encrypt the user's password with my own encrypted password or can I just saved it, hashed, in a session?

Comment: Your original problem was that you  needed the user password to not be changed. This way you store it safely and do not change it. You need to write down exactly what needs to happen for your code to work the way you expect. You need to get the two string encryption / decryption routines working. Then it  will be clear how to use them.

Comment: here's what i'm going to do: 1) when the user logs in i control his password with the password_verify() function. 2) when it's time to encrypt the string i don't ask him nothing, instead I encrypt the data with my own key, generated with defuse function. 3) when it's time do decrypt i ask user's password only to decide if he can actually decrypt. This way I don't need to save anywhere the user's password. Hope this is secure enough :)

Comment: Sounds quite useful. It may be useful to others once you have used it for a while. Please post an  answer of how you went on with it. Seriously - It  sounds like a viable approach to me.

Comment: @RyanVincent all right. Once i've updated the code and i'm certain that it works perfectly, I'll post an answer on everything I made, with your very welcome help, to resolve the problem. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Any problems then update the question with the code and we will try and help. :)